# C/C++ Cocos2dx Object return null after calling schedule

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am newbie for Cocos development
Now, I am facing the problem when calling schedule
I have 2 scenes (Scene1 and Scene2) and Object1. 
Scene1 is main, has a menu to change to Scene2.
In createScenes2() function I modify the values of Object1, as below

```
Chap5.h
Scene *scene1,*scene2;
int ount;
```

Chap5.cpp

```
scene1 = Scene::create();
scene1->retain();
scene2 = createScene2();
scene2->retain();
auto nodeItems = Node::create();
nodeItems->setName("nodeItems");

auto menuNode = Node::create();
menuNode->setName("menuNode");
int index = 2;

auto thisSceneLabel = Label::createWithTTF("This Is A Scene 1",
        "Marker Felt.ttf", 64);

auto menuItem1 = MenuItemFont::create("Make A New Scene");
menuItem1->setFontNameObj("Marker Felt.ttf");
menuItem1->setFontSizeObj(64);  menuItem1->setName("menuItem1");

menuItem1->setCallback([&](cocos2d::Ref *sender) {

    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene2);

    });

auto menu = Menu::create(menuItem1, NULL);
menu->setName("menu");
menuNode->addChild(menu, 1);
menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);

scene1->addChild(menuNode, 2);
scene1->setTag(1);


this->addChild(scene1);

return true;
```

In createScenes2() I modified Count value

```
Scene* Chap5::createScene2() {
 count=999999;
scene2->schedule(schedule_selector(Chap5::updateCount), 0.5); // call      schedule to updates
```

}
but in the method updates, count is not updated

```
void Chap5::initSprite(float dt) {
CCLOG("count = %d", count);}
```

My problem is count not get value after transaction to Scenes2 and call schedule method
Anyboby can let me know why
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: So are the scenes subclasses of `cocos2d::Layer` with their own `createScene` method?  It's unusual to create scenes and then schedule methods *outside* of the scene class; the scenes should take care of arrange for scheduled methods themselves.

Comment: Thank u for response!
can you give me example, and tell more details ? or help to modify my code ! I am really don't understant what you mean....

Comment: There are tons of examples in the Cocos2d-x `cpp-tests` directory.

Comment: Actually the `HelloWorldScene` that is part of every new Cocos2d-x project should show you how to write a custom scene.

Comment: I tried by create another scene class. But it same. Could you give me an small example to resolve this.
When I call schedule in replaced scene, all object that init in createScenes() will be return null

Comment: I tried by created another Scene class but could not resolve.
Could you give me a small sample.
The  value of object in the schedule function is getting incorrect value
I hope you can provide a sample for me.

Comment: Is `Chap5` a `Layer`? If so, I guess you're on the wrong way. I haven't seen anyone add a scene to layer. And, when a node/sprite/layer/scene is not running, its sheduled functions will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you may be getting a null return is because in your createScene2, the variable scene2 is not instantiated and your method is not returning Scene* as a return type:

```
Scene* Chap5::createScene2()
 { 
    count=999999;
    scene2->schedule(schedule_selector(Chap5::updateCount), 0.5); // call schedule to updates
 }
```

What you probably want to do should look something like this:

```
Scene* Chap5::createScene2()
{ 
    Scene* scene2 = Scene::create ();
    count=999999;
    scene2->schedule(schedule_selector(Chap5::updateCount), 0.5); // call schedule to updates
    return scene2;
}
```

I would advice to keep each scene in its own .h and .cpp files for easy readability and following common conventions

A good way to learn as a beginner is by following examples:
https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe